# Flex 4.6 + BlazeDS 4 + Spring 3.x

Tags: apache-flex, spring, spring-mvc, flex4.5, blazeds

I'm trying to integrate Flex 4 with Spring 3.x using BlazeDS 4, but when I try to run Flex Web Application that tries to access a method it throws me the following error message:

```
"[RPC Fault faultString="Send failed" faultCode="Client.Error.MessageSend" faultDetail="Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Status 404: url: 'http://localhost:8080/KlinASM/messagebroker/amf'"]"
```

I'm using Tomcat 7 as web app server...and I have used this tutorial: http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/flex-4-and-spring-3

I can provide you with more details about this project if you need, but almost everything is the as in that tutorial

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you see when you type that url directly into your browser? It should be a white page.

Comment: looks like you missed something in the configuration or your blazeDS ws is not running :) recheck the tutorial

Comment: Yes, u're right I have missed RDSDispatchServlet config & I did everything from scratch and now its running! :) thank you anyway..